# Why is there a ! in the password hash?

Tags: users, shadow, accounts

In `/etc/shadow`, I have a line that begins:

```
ubuntu:!$6$Pi4BKmX8$........................
```

Why is there a `!` before the `$6$` in the hash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the password is locked.  Tools, such as `usermod -L` add a `!` to the password to invalidate it. `usermod -U` removes the `!`.

From `man 5 shadow`

> If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3), for instance ! or *, the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means).

Comment: Thnx @garethTheRed :)